# Placing RadioButtun Or Checkbox, For each Column Header in Kendo UI grid, for deletion Updation purpose

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Current scenario, demand deletion of the Kendo Gird column at runtime, I was wondering if there is any way to place checkbox or radio Button for Column header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this,

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TwoModelInSinglePageModel.SampleModel>()
    .Name("grid12")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.studentclass).HeaderTemplate("<input id='selectall' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox'  />").ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox_#=inx#' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleDescription).HeaderTemplate("<input id='chkSampleDescription' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox'  />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleCode).HeaderTemplate("<input id='chkSampleCode' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox'  />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleItems).HeaderTemplate("<input id='chkSampleItems' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox'  />");
    })

        .Pageable()
            .Navigatable()
        //.Filterable()
             .Sortable()
             .Groupable()
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("_GridItemDataBound"))
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.inx))

            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Test"))
     )
  )
```